# How do I refresh or reload scripts in 3DS Max?

Tags: maxscript

When I create Maxscript scripts in 3DSMAX I place them in the `startup` folder in the installation directory of Max and start them via the `MAXScript` section under `Utilities`.

When I make changes however I need to restart Max in order for it to load the scripts again before they take affect.

**How can I force Max to reload the scripts in the `startup` folder?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any reason to use this approach? Instead of using scripted utilities, have a look at rollout floaters or dialogs, both ways are much more manageable and user friendly. To make your scripts easily accessible, wrap them in macroscript definition or just run them via MAXScript menu in the menubar.

For example for a sample utility like this

```
utility main "Main"
(
    rollout sub "Rollout"
    (
        button btn "Button"
    )
)
```

the dialog version would be

```
try destroyDialog sub catch()
rollout sub "Rollout"
(
    button btn "Button"
)
createDialog sub
```

and the macroscript definition

```
macroscript main category:"MyTools" buttonText:"Main"
(
    rollout sub "Rollout"
    (
        button btn "Button"
    )

    on execute do
    (
        destroyDialog sub
        createDialog sub
    )
)
```

Comment: Only that I was not aware I could do that. Thank you! This will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible alternative seems using `fileIn(getThisScriptFilename())` in the script itself.

If errors are not a concern, just reloading separate file should do:

```
fileIn("btn_1_code_source_file.ms")
btn_1_code()
```

And this especially useful to prevent UI inactive state after errors:

```
utility YourTool <...>

fn btn_1_code =(
    throw("test")
)

on btn_1 pressed do(
    CloseUtility(YourTool)
    gc()
    fileIn(getThisScriptFilename())
    OpenUtility(YourTool)

    btn_1_code()
)
```

In the example above, `btn_1_code` can also be passed as argument to `fileIn()` common wrapper to make code cleaner.