# Reset or reload max script?

Tags: maxscript

I have a script that has a bunch of controls and rollouts and it is shown using a rollout floater.
I need to have a button that returns the script into its original state with its original values. like when I closed and reopened it.
there are several changes during the usage of the script and the user needs to close and reopen the script every time he/she needs to use it. and there is a lot of opening and closing.
I wanted to have a button that resets or at least reopens the script on its own.

Comment: Pair of possible answers is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17008711/10141885)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps put your initializations in a function and call it from `on <rollout> open do (<func>)` and on button pressed.